# По параметрам с одной таблицы выбрать с другой C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, core, ef

У меня есть табличка Cars и табличка CarsForSale к примеру
В таблице CarsForSale у меня есть колонки Id, Name, Type, Mark, CarId
Как с помощью EF Core выбрать те Cars у которых в таблице CarsForSale Type = 1 и Mark="BMW" например?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CarsForSale[] carsForSale = new CarsForSale[0];
carsForSale.Where(car => car.Type == 1 && car.Mark == "BMW").Include(car => car.Cars).Select(car => car.Cars).ToArray();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]